# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку"

Tags: c#

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
> "System.IO.Ports, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не
> удается найти указанный файл."

Написал библиотеку классов dll. Целевая платформа `.Net Stantard 2.0`. Для работы была необходима [библиотека](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/) `SerialPort` (`IO.Ports`), которая была установлена через `NuGet`.

Далее библиотека подключилась в проект, собранный под платформу `.Net Fraemwork 4.6.1`, где подключена директива `IO.Ports`.

Но при выполнении кода выдается вышеописанное исключение. Я как понимаю, конфликтуют библиотеки `.NET Fraemwork` и `.NET Standard`. Не подскажете, как исправить это исключение?

Comment: Версия `Version=4.0.1.0` .Net целевой сборки вам не о чём не говорит? это отличимый путь каталога от того куда установлены пакеты с nuget.org

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось решение простое. В проекте, куда подключаете библиотеку через диспетчер пакетов NuGet установите -System.IO.Ports

Средства - Диспетчер пакетов NuGet - Управление пакетами...